# Read contents of uploaded HTML file to string in JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, multipartform-data

I need to upload an HTML file using a servlet and put its contents in a string. The request comes in multi-part/form-data.

I am trying to use `Part filepart = request.getPart("file")` but that's not working. I need to know if there is anyway to achieve this without using third party APIs like Apache Commons FileUploader.

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Any error messages? What are they?

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part.The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

This is the response that I can see. i am pretty new to this and this is all i have been able to get so far

Comment: Are you attempting to use [Servlet 3.0 multipart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String)) functionality? or the Jetty [MultiPartFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/MultiPartFilter.html)?